# Store query result in a array - what is wrong?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a query:

```
mysql_select_db($database_dbconfig, $dbconfig);
$query_Holidays = "SELECT substring(data,9,2) AS days_holidays FROM database_holidays WHERE database_holidays.data <> ''";
$Holidays = mysql_query($query_Holidays, $dbconfig) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Holidays = mysql_fetch_assoc($Holidays);
$totalRows_Holidays = mysql_num_rows($Holidays);
```

Results are like this:

```
14    15    21    30
```

and

```
$totalRows_Holidays = 4
```

if I add this: (in order to get an array)

```
$days_calendar = array();
while ($row_Holidays = mysql_fetch_assoc($Holidays)) {
    $days_calendar[] = $row_Holidays['days_holidays'];}
print_r($days_calendar);
```

I get as result:

```
Array([0]=>15[1]=>21[2]=>30)
```

Where is 14?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do `mysql_fetch_assoc($Holidays)` you recover one row, if you are executing this before the `while` loop, then the first row (14) will be escaped.

Remove this first `mysql_fetch_assoc` and all will be ok.

And do not use `mysql_*` functions, they are deprecated and will not be included in future versions, use `PDO` or `mysqli_*` functions

PS: Maybe this is a comment but i don't have permission

Comment: Nope i don't think this can be a comment. My +1.

Answer (score 2):

When you call the first time

```
 $row_Holidays = mysql_fetch_assoc($Holidays);
```

You are actually skipping the first row.  So, the resulting code should be

```
 mysql_select_db($database_dbconfig, $dbconfig);
 $query_Holidays = "SELECT substring(data,9,2) AS days_holidays 
      FROM database_holidays     
      WHERE database_holidays.data <> ''";
 $Holidays = mysql_query($query_Holidays, $dbconfig) or die(mysql_error());
 $totalRows_Holidays = mysql_num_rows(Holidays);
 $days_calendar = array();
 while ($row_Holidays = mysql_fetch_assoc($Holidays)) 
 {
     $days_calendar[] = $row_Holidays['days_holidays'];
 }
 print_r($days_calendar);
```

Ok, and now that you get it working, please consider using mysqli_ functions!! :)

Comment: It is working. But the problem was identified above! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
  $days_calendar = array();
    while ($row_Holidays = mysql_fetch_array($Holidays)) {
        $days_calendar[] = $row_Holidays['days_holidays'];}
    print_r($days_calendar);
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace everything from

```
$row_Holidays = mysql_fetch_assoc($Holidays);
```

with

```
$totalRows_Holidays = mysql_num_rows(Holidays);
if ($totalRows_Holidays > 0){
  while ($row_Holidays = mysql_fetch_assoc($Holidays)) {
    $days_calendar[] = $row_Holidays['days_holidays'];
  }
}
print_r($days_calendar);
```

That first line is where the 14 was called. Using my code resolves the issue.

Hope this answer helps.

Comment: Also, do not use **mysql_*** functions; they are deprecated and security risk. Use **PDO** or **MySQLi** instead.

Comment: It is working. But the problem was identified above! Thank you!

Comment: @MugurUngureanu No problem; glad to help. Now, work on migrating your database accessing functions from **mysql_*** to **PDO**; your applications will thank you for it :)

Answer (score 1):

try this ...

```
    mysql_select_db($database_dbconfig, $dbconfig);
    $query_Holidays = "SELECT substring(data,9,2) AS days_holidays FROM database_holidays   WHERE database_holidays.data <> ''";
    $Holidays = mysql_query($query_Holidays, $dbconfig) or die(mysql_error());
    //$row_Holidays = mysql_fetch_assoc($Holidays);
    //$totalRows_Holidays = mysql_num_rows(Holidays);
    $days_calendar = array();
while ($row_Holidays = mysql_fetch_assoc($Holidays)) {
    $days_calendar[] = $row_Holidays['days_holidays'];}
print_r($days_calendar);
```

Comment: It is working. But the problem was identified above! Thank you!